# Removing specific duplicates from an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array like this

```
const ex = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        sender: "12345678",
        receiver: {
            name: "simi",
            age: 20,
            city: "New York"
        },
         time: 12:30 am
    },
    {
        name: 'Jane',
        sender: {
            name: "simi",
            age: 20,
            city: "New York"
        },
        receiver: "12345678",
        time: 1:00 pm
    }
]
```

In this array, the sender property value in the first object is equal to the receiver property value in the second object.
Is there a way I can check and produce only one occurence of this value, that is, just one object in which the value is present

Comment: what does this value mean object value or property value?

Comment: property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const ex = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        sender: "12345678",
        receiver: {
            name: "simi",
            age: 20,
            city: "New York"
        },
         time: "12:30 am"
    },
    {
        name: 'Jane',
        sender: {
            name: "simi",
            age: 20,
            city: "New York"
        },
        receiver: "12345678",
        time: "1:00 pm"
    }
]

let map = {}
ex.forEach(e => {
     let obj = null;
     if(e.sender instanceof Object) 
          obj = e.sender;
     else if(e.receiver instanceof Object) 
          obj = e.receiver;
     if(!obj) return;
     let key = obj.name+obj.age+obj.city;
     if(!map[key])
          map[key] = e;
});

console.log(Object.values(map));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, what if I still want to have it in array. Lets say there's a possibility of have several scenarios like that

Comment: @SimiloluwaOdeyemi ``Object.values(map)`` is another array containing the new unique elements.